# Prove the following equation has infinitely many solutions and the set of solutions is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to prove that $\sin(xy)+\cos(x+y)=x^2+y$ has infinitely many solutions in x,y and the set of all solutions is a closed set in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Proving is closed seems fairly easy. $f: \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $
 $f(x,y)=\sin(xy)+\cos(x+y)-x^2-y=0$.

$A=\{0\}$ is closed so $f^{-1}(A)$ is also closed by continuity.

Now, I have no idea how to prove that there are infinitely many solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: The set if solutions is in $\mathbb R^2$. It can't be closed in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Hint: the equation has an infinite number of solutions along the curve $y=-x^2$.

Comment: @Paul That was super helpful. Now I feel weird I did not see it!

Comment: @Paul Please don't answer questions in the comments.